# Inline confirmation button

Tags: html, css

I am new to modal buttons. For some reason the Delete button does not display the question **"are you sure to delete?"** and simply perform the delete action. I need the confirmation to be displayed, it is an important validation. I keep trying to find the solution with no results yet. I attach the source code. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
 }

 .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
 }

 .topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
 }

 .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
 }

 p.centrartextoparrafo {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
 }

 h1.centrartextoh1titulopaginaprincipal {
    text-align: center;
 }

 h2.centrartextoh2titulopaginaprincipal {
    text-align: center;
 }


 #copyright {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
 }

 table.center {
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
 }

 table, th, td {
    border: 20px solid white;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
 }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
 }
 .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 }  
 }




</style>


<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
     <a href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}" class="active">Dashboard</a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
     <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
     </a>
     <form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="get" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name...">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    </form>
    <a href="{{ url_for('new_nadador') }}">New</a></li>
    <a href="{{ url_for('nadadores') }}">List swimmers</a></li>

</div>
<script>
 function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
 }
</script>


<div class="container">
    {# Flashed messages #}
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
     {% for category, message in messages %}
      <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}" role="alert">{{ message }}</div>
     {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
   {# End Flashed messages #}
 </div>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}"></script>

<h2 class="centrartextoh2titulopaginaprincipal">Swimmers</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">

 <tr>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Surname</th>
    <th scope="col">e-mail</th>
<th scope="col">Phone</th>
<th scope="col"></th> 
<th scope="col"></th>
</tr>


{% for nadador in nadadores %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ nadador.cedula }}</td>
        <td>{{ nadador.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ nadador.surname }}</td>
        <td>{{ nadador.email }}</td>
  <td>{{ nadador.phone }}</td>
  <td class="text-right">
    <div class="row">
      <form action="{{ url_for('nadadores_delete') }}" method="post" class="pull-right">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ nadador.id }}">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="confirmation" {# data-title="¿Are you sure to delete?" #} value="Delete">
      </form>
      <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="{{ url_for('edit_nadador', id=nadador.id) }}">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </td>
{% endfor %}
</table>


<div id="copyright">
  Derechos reservados 2020 &copy; (022)
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I enclose a screenshot of the screen where the two buttons are displayed. The Edit button works fine; the Delete button does not display the confirmation question before deleting the record.

[image]

Comment: Add `onClick` event to your button

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle so that we can play around with it?

Comment: @Sujil Majarhan Please here is the link to JSFiddle.  Hope helps.  I did customize the code to display what actually is relevant.https://jsfiddle.net/jativar/9a2815dL/15/#collaborate

Comment: I don't see any code related to the modal

Comment: @Sujil Maharjan Is this code related to the modal box?  This section of the code was working before.

Comment: <div class="row">
      <form action="{{ url_for('nadadores_delete') }}" method="post" class="pull-right">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ nadador.id }}">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="confirmation" {# data-title="¿Are you sure to delete?" #} value="Delete">
      </form>
      <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="{{ url_for('edit_nadador', id=nadador.id) }}">Edit</a>
    </div>

Comment: Not sure where is the missing code to make it works again.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
<h2 class="centrartextoh2titulopaginaprincipal">Nadadores</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">

    <tr>
        <th scope="col">CI</th>
        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
        <th scope="col">Correo Electronico</th>
    <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
    <th scope="col"></th> <!-- Espacio de columna para el boton Editar   -->
    <th scope="col"></th> <!-- Espacio de columna para el boton Eliminar -->
    </tr>


    {% for nadador in nadadores %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ nadador.cedula }}</td>
            <td>{{ nadador.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ nadador.surname }}</td>
            <td>{{ nadador.email }}</td>
       <td>{{ nadador.phone }}</td>
      <td class="text-right">
        <div class="row">
          <form action="{{ url_for('nadadores_delete') }}" method="post" class="pull-right">
           <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ nadador.id }}">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="confirmation" data-title="¿Esta seguro?" value="Eliminar">
          </form>
          <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="{{ url_for('edit_nadador', id=nadador.id) }}">Editar</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>


{# 
  Solution:

  JS
  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

  Many components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they 
  require jQuery, Popper.js, and JavaScript plugins. 
  Place the following TAG script's near the end of your pages, right before the closing 
  body tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our 
  JavaScript plugins.  
 #}

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}"></script>
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onClick` event solution

```js
function checkFunction() {
    if (confirm("Confirm")) {
      return true
    }
    return false
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="return checkFunction();" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="confirmation" {# data-title="¿Are you sure to delete?" #} value="Delete">
```